# Angular expression not evaluating properly in Ionic popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, expression

I am trying to display data from a JSON object that is within a controller's scope. This would happen within a function that calls an Ionic popup. What I am trying to do is display this data in a template that would be used to build the popup itself. The below function dwells within the controller:

```
this.showAlert = function(i) {

this.pref = [{
  label: "Foo",
  addr_l1: "Bar",
  addr_l2: "Baz",
  locality: "Pez"
}];

var popUp = '<p>dcd{{pickupCtrl.pref[' + i + '].addr_l1}}</p>' +
  '<p>{{pickupCtrl.pref[' + i + '].addr_l2}}</p>' +
  '<p>{{pickupCtrl.pref[' + i + '].locality}}</p>';

var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
  title: this.pref[i].label,
  template: popUp,
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Cancel'
  }, {
    text: '<b>OK</b>',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      // add choice
    }
  }, ]

});
```

}

For some reason, the template is not displaying the Angular expression, but it does display the "dcd" text I added as a test. This means that there is something wrong in the way I am calling the expression itself.

How should I specify the variable within the template so that it properly displays?

Comment: What about binding the values before passing to the alert? 

'<p> dcd ' + pickupCtrl.pref[i].addr_l1 + '</p>'....

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that I forgot to add `scope: $scope` as part of the parameters for the Ionic Popup. Basically from:

```
title: this.pref[i].label,
template: popUp,
buttons: [{
  text: 'Cancel'
}, {
  text: '<b>OK</b>',
  type: 'button-positive',
  onTap: function(e) {
    // add choice
  }
}, ]
```

to this:

```
title: this.pref[i].label,
template: popUp,
scope: $scope, // ADD THIS
buttons: [{
  text: 'Cancel'
}, {
  text: '<b>OK</b>',
  type: 'button-positive',
  onTap: function(e) {
    // add choice
  }
}, ]
```